# Permalinks for pages

Tags: permalinks, pages

Why can't i edit the permalinks for my **pages**? I got a 4 layer structure,

Home
Solutions
Machines
Steel

so I want my URL structure to be [www.domein.com/solutions/machines/steel](http://www.domein.com/solutions/machines/steel) but where can i do this??
I made all the catagories in the also 4 layer strucure. But at the permalinks editor i can only choose Post or Products...

I find it strange that I cant do the same for my Pages...

I hope this makes sense, and someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make each page a parent of one another.

To assign a parent page to a page, navigate to the page you want to assign a parent page too, then in the right sidebar you will see **Page Attributes** and a dropdown menu labelled **Parent**, whatever page you selected in that list will become its parent.

So, Solutions will be the parent of Machines and Machines will be the parent of Steel. In doing so will generate a permalink structure as follows /solutions/machines/steel, this URL will only show up for the page Steel.

Example:
[image]

Hope that helps.